# sync Framework for Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, microsoft-sync-framework

Has anyone got sync framework to work on a mobile device as a sync mechanism in place of RDA or Merge replication?

If yes, could you point me to any resources available.

If one was to start a green field compact framework based application, what would one use as the sync mechanism (sync framework/RDA/Merge replication/any other...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example SyncFX for [SQL Server CE](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=3422).

Here is a link comparing the [technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281959.aspx#sectionToggle4).  Towards the bottom in particular is a bit about deciding which technology to use.

From a CF green field standpoint I would use SyncFX.  It seems like Microsoft is getting away from RDA and SyncFX is a programmer-centric instead of DBA centric (like replication).